# Data should bind in the below given format in javascript

Tags: javascript

My JSON data is in format:

```
"x": {
        "xEnabled": "N",
        "1-a": "0.0",
        "2-b": "0.0",
        "1-c": "0",
        "2-d": "0"
    },
    "y": {
        "yEnabled": "N",
        "1-a": "0.0",
        "2-b": "0.0",
        "1-c": "0",
        "2-d": "0"
    },
    "z": {
        "zEnabled": "N",
        "1-a": "0.0",
        "2-b": "0.0",
        "1-c": "0",
        "2-d": "0"
    },
    "w": {
        "wEnabled": "N",
        "1-a": "0.0",
        "2-b": "0.0",
        "1-c": "0",
        "2-d": "0"
    }
```

I want to bind this data to HTML how should I bind this data to get in this format

```
Data    1-a      2-b    1-c     2-d
x       0.0      0.0    0       0
y       0.0      0.0    0       0
z       0.0      0.0    0       0
w       0.0      0.0    0       0
```

Comment: Add more description. Read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) page.

Comment: Use `table` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data = {
  "x": {
    "xEnabled": "N",
    "1-a": "0.0",
    "2-b": "0.0",
    "1-c": "0",
    "2-d": "0"
  },
  "y": {
    "yEnabled": "N",
    "1-a": "0.0",
    "2-b": "0.0",
    "1-c": "0",
    "2-d": "0"
  },
  "z": {
    "zEnabled": "N",
    "1-a": "0.0",
    "2-b": "0.0",
    "1-c": "0",
    "2-d": "0"
  },
  "w": {
    "wEnabled": "N",
    "1-a": "0.0",
    "2-b": "0.0",
    "1-c": "0",
    "2-d": "0"
  }
};

var a = document.querySelector("#t");
Object.keys(data).forEach((e, i) => {
  a.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + e + '</td><td>' + data[e]["1-a"] + '</td><td>' + data[e]["2-b"] + '</td><td>' + data[e]["1-c"] + '</td><td>' + data[e]["2-d"] + '</td></tr>';
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>1-a</td>
    <td>2-b</td>
    <td>1-c</td>
    <td>2-d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```